# Error when putting facebook dependency in android app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

I am creating a facebook login option in android app in Android Studio. When i put

```
 compile group: 'com.facebook.android', name: 'facebook-android-sdk', version: '4.26.0'
```

dependency in build.gradle, an error is coming as:-

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0
```

What is the Reason.

The gradle file is :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.health"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk
    compile group: 'com.facebook.android', name: 'facebook-android-sdk', version: '4.26.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Show your *gradle*.

Comment: gradle file added ...

Answer (score 0):

put below line in dependency in build.gradle;

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
```

Comment: There is no need to change as *4.18.0* because the OP version *4.26.0* is already available on *developers facebook*.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of this.**

```
compile group: 'com.facebook.android', name: 'facebook-android-sdk', version: '4.26.0'
```

**Do this.**

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
```

And make sure you have this inside *classpath gradle*.

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }    
}
```

Then *clean* and *rebuild* your project.